# consume/return a JSON response when executing flow using Spring boot API

Tags: spring, spring-boot, corda

I'm a beginner in corda and I'm trying to execute flows using Spring boot API. When I used:

> @PostMapping(value = [ "create-iou" ], produces = [ TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE ] , headers = [ "Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded" ])

my flow is getting executed (by testing it using insomnia). But When I changed it to

> @PostMapping(value = [ "create-iou" ], produces = [ APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE ], headers = [ "Content-Type=application/json" ])

It gives me a 406 not acceptable error: No body returned for response.

Here's the API I've created/copied:

```
@PostMapping(value = [ "create-iou" ], produces = [ TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE ] , headers = [ "Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded" ])
fun createIOU(request: HttpServletRequest): ResponseEntity<String> {
    val iouValue = request.getParameter("iouValue").toInt()
    val partyName = request.getParameter("partyName")
        ?: return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Query parameter 'partyName' must not be null.\n")
    if (iouValue <= 0 ) {
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Query parameter 'iouValue' must be non-negative.\n")
    }
    val partyX500Name = CordaX500Name.parse(partyName)
    val otherParty = proxy.wellKnownPartyFromX500Name(partyX500Name) ?: return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Party named $partyName cannot be found.\n")

    return try {
        val signedTx = proxy.startTrackedFlow(::Initiator, iouValue, otherParty).returnValue.getOrThrow()
        ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body("Transaction id ${signedTx.id} committed to ledger.\n")

    } catch (ex: Throwable) {
        logger.error(ex.message, ex)
        ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(ex.message!!)
    }
}
```

I would like to return something like this:

```
{ 
iouValue: 99, 
lender: PartyA, 
borrower: PartyB
}
```

When executing the flow using http endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the RPC connection libraries provided by Corda:

```
import net.corda.client.rpc.CordaRPCClient
import net.corda.client.rpc.CordaRPCConnection
```

Take a look to [this example](https://github.com/corda/samples/blob/release-V4/spring-webserver/server-kotlin/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/server/NodeRPCConnection.kt) to see how to use them.

You are not showing how your proxy is instantiate, but you need to instantiate a proxy to connect via RPC to the node, like so:

```
val rpcAddress = NetworkHostAndPort(host, rpcPort)
val rpcClient = CordaRPCClient(rpcAddress)
val rpcConnection = rpcClient.start(username, password)
proxy = rpcConnection.proxy
```

and once you have the proxy, you can create SpringBoot APIs to call that proxy that makes the RPC calls:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/") 
class StandardController(rpc: NodeRPCConnection) {

    private val proxy = rpc.proxy
    
    @GetMapping(value = ["/addresses"], produces = arrayOf("text/plain"))
    private fun addresses() = proxy.nodeInfo().addresses.toString()

    @GetMapping(value = ["/identities"], produces = arrayOf("text/plain"))
    private fun identities() = proxy.nodeInfo().legalIdentities.toString()
```